# Split chunk at the end of file when patching a file

Tags: git

Is it possible to make git split a chunk in two when two separate code pieces are added to the end of the file when running `git add -p`?

Comment: If any of the answers below have helped you, or solved your problems, please consider upvoting the useful ones and possibly accepting the one that solved your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to try is Michael Turczyn's solution: `git add --patch filename`. When you get to the final hunk, try `s` to split it. If that does not work, you have the option to manually edit the current hunk by hitting `e`.

The instructions on editing the hunk are shown in the editor that will pop up. For the case you describe, keep the lines starting with `+` that you want to add, and delete the lines starting with `+` that you want to be left unstaged for now.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. For same answer with an example see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68099959/6659668) by @matt below.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by commenting-out the lines you don't want in the first hunk (for additions) or removing the leading `-` (for deletions). This means that only the changes still in the diff will be staged (added to the index). For example, let's consider the following changes to two files (additions and deletions to be complete) shown by `git diff`:

```
f1.txt              f2.txt
@@ -1 +1,3 @@       @@ -1,3 +1 @@
 test                test
+line1              -line1
+line2              -line2
```

After executing **`git patch -p`**, you choose `e` for *edit* when the hunks come up. In the editor, comment out the parts you don't want to stage (for `f1.txt` / additions) and/or remove the `-` for deleted parts you don't want to stage (for `f2.txt` / deletions):

```
f1.txt              f2.txt
@@ -1 +1,3 @@       @@ -1,3 +1 @@
 test                test
+line1              -line1           <= leave as is (this will be added)
#+line2              line2           <= commented-out / '-' removed
```

After this, `git diff` shows the desired result which you could commit now:

```
f1.txt              f2.txt
@@ -1 +1,3 @@       @@ -1,3 +1 @@
 test                test
 line1               line1
+line2              -line2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try running `git add --patch filename`, but it's not guaranteed that git will recognize and allow splitting into desired parts.

For example, I added following at the end of my file:

```
// First hunk to commit
        
// Second hunk to commit separately
```

and run `git add --path` and entered interactive mode, where you can decide if you want further split hunks or accept them, etc.

`s` stands for "splitting hunk", but when I specify it, git complains that:

> Sorry, cannot split this hunk

So I am afraid that you have to try on your own, if your hunk will be possible to achieve.

Alternatively, just delete the one part of a code (and copy to notepad temporarily), add and commit. Then just paste back that code and again add and commit :)

Comment: Yes, I was specifically looking for a way to overcome "Sorry, cannot split this hunk."

Answer (score 0):

`git add -p` is definitely useful, however it will only get you so far if you want to do some detailed editing of your file.

Just as a reminder, another way to is to simply backup your file and edit it.

Here is a would be procedure :

```
# 1. stage the easy parts
git add -p -- the/file

# 2. create a copy of your file on disk
cp the/file the/file.mine

# 3. reset `the/file` to its staged state
git checkout the/file

# 4. now either :
#  - edit the file directly
code the/file                    # obviously, any editor works
#  - or use a visual diff viewer to have a view similar to `git add -p`
kdiff3 the/file.mine the/file    # again, any diff viewer works

# 5. add and commit
git add the/file
git commit

# 6. restore 'the/file.mine'
mv the/file.min the/file
```